# Is there a way how to programatically acces my Google Wallet Merchant Account, so I can check from my phone easily how much I make every day etc?

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-pay

I am developer, selling my apps.

But I dont always have access to my PC, so I was thinking writing a simple app which would access my Wallet Account to see how much I earned this day/week/month.

Is there any API and some working example how to do this? THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know about the [official Play console app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole)? It lets you check financial data among other things, like reply to reviews.

If you do need programmatic access there isn't an API, but you can [Download reports from Google Cloud Storage](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export) which has an API. There are instructions on that page for both a command line tool access and a client library and service account.

Comment: Yes, but that doesnt solve my problem. I have 8 different apps, I dont want to check manually Revenue for each app, I just wanna see total Revenue for all apps. Like on webpage in browser: https://payments.google.com/payments where I can see how much I earn every day, and also subtotal for each month.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not just access the web page from the phone?

Comment: I wanted to make some simple app which would show results in some easier readable form, eventually also some predictions or estimation of trends, etc.

Comment: I added some more details in an edit of a possible solution.

Comment: thank you. its not exactly what i was looking for, but your answer is best possible in this situation.